# C# Generic methods / Polymorphism

Tags: c#, generics, polymorphism

I have the following code that I use to close a stream.

```
void CloseStream(Stream s)
{
    if (s != null)
        s.Close();
}

void CloseStream(HttpWebResponse s)
{
    if (s != null)
        s.Close();
}

void CloseStream(StreamReader s)
{
    if (s != null)
        s.Close();
}
```

The code works perfectly but I would like to refactor the 3 methods if it's possible.
Ideally the method would look like that:

```
void CloseStream(Object obj)
{
    obj.Close();
}
```

But I cannot do obj.Close() because the Object class does not implements such a method.
So I was wondering if any of you had any idea how to resolve it.

Thanks for your time,
Kevin

Answer (score 9, accepted):

All these 'streams' are [disposable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.aspx), so use `Dispose()` instead of `Close()`:

```
void CloseStream(IDisposable s)
{
    if (s != null)
        s.Dispose();
}
```

Also consider to use functionality built-in .Net Framework - [`using`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) statement will automatically dispose disposable object without any additional calls to `CloseStream`:

```
using(StreamReader reader = File.OpenText(path))// create disposable here
{
    // use disposable
}
```

This code will automatically check if disposable is not `null` and dispose it at the end of `using` block. Code above block will compile into:

```
StreamReader reader = File.OpenText(path);

try
{
    // use disposable
}
finally // will be executed even in case of exception
{
   if (reader != null)
      reader.Dispose(); // internally calls Close()
}
```

Answer (score 4):

All three classes implement `IDisposable`, and the `Dispose` method closes the underlying stream, so you can call that instead:

```
void CloseStream(IDisposable s)
{
    if (s != null)
        s.Dispose();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

They should all implement `IDisposable` which implements `Dispose` (which does the same work as `Close`).

So try:

```
void CloseStream(IDispsable obj)
{
    obj.Dispose();
}
```